# ruby rack - can't modify ARGV in middleware?

Tags: ruby, rack, middleware, argv

I can't seem to append to ARGV within a preprocssing piece of rack middleware. Anyone know how rack handles ARGV when middleware exists? How can I modify ARGV within my middleware? There has to be a way to do this, I'm just at a complete loss.

```
ARGV << "--debug"
ARGV << "--host" << "localhost"

class Pre
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    if some_env_related_logic
      ARGV << "--test"
    end
    @app.call(env)
  end

end

require 'Somecommand'

use Pre
run Somecommand
```

Right now that "--test" argument does NOT get added to the ARGV available within Somecommand.

UPDATE:

It appears the Somecommand app makes use of ARGV in the initialize method. That happens before the first piece of middleware. So now the question is: how do I create a rack app that calls this second rack app? Since I need to evaluate the ENV before instantiation of the seconds rack app.

Comment: I am curious why you are trying to change ARGV on a request-by-request basis, would it not be better to add specific keys to the env hash which the Somecommand app could then interpret?

Comment: Have you tried setting the variables you want directly, rather than indirectly via ARGV? This is Ruby - you can open any class and set anything you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
class Pre
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    # To be safe, reset the ARGV and rebuild, add any other items if needed
    ARGV.clear
    ARGV << "--debug"
    ARGV << "--host" << "localhost"

    if some_env_related_logic
      ARGV << "--test"
    end
    Somecommand.new.call(env)
  end    
end

require 'Somecommand'

# Note the change, Somecommand is no longer mentioned here 
run Pre
```